# Add css classes in Razor conditionally based on Valid state of model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have pretty standard MVC Razor code

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-8 ">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

I would like to add a CSS class of "has-error" to the form-group if the validation for the model.Description has failed but I can't work out the syntax.
I have found lots of examples of conditionally adding the text but not based on the validation state of the model.

Comment: The framework already adds a `class="input-validation-error"` if its invalid. Just style that class.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this can help you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isValid = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData.ModelState.IsValid));
    if (isValid != 'true') {
        $('.form-selector').addClass('has-error');
    }
</script>
```